# Dynamic DNS (DDNS) updates from dnsmasq for use with bind9

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dhcp, dnsmasq

Previously I ran dnsmasq on an OpenWRT to provide DNS and DHCP functionality, because this is, what it is intended for. I want to offload the DNS part to an already configured bind9 (running on Ubuntu), which is quite easy so far except the resolution of clients, which got their IP dynamically assigned by dnsmasq acting as DHCP Server. I want to know:

- Is it possible to perform dynamic DNS Updates from dnsmasq to bind, so that bind is able to resolve dynamically assigned DHCP hosts?
- and if yes, is it possible to have zonefiles, which contain static records (for routers, switches, APs, servers, etc) AND dynamic DHCP hosts (or in short: a zonefile which is filled up but not exclusively used throughout dnsmasq and maybe conflicting because of some zonefile serial-number-mess)

I want to avoid ISC-DHCPD, and use dnsmasq instead, because in the future I additionally plan to build a PXE setup.

Comment: Just for the record: you can build a PXE environment using isc-dhcpd as well.